# Android Game : OnCompletionListener for the Music in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am playing a music in Libgdx game. I wish to have a listener like this to play the music and do a specific process after that. But the program control never reaches the onCompletionListerner part.

```
 private void playMusic() {
    gameMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/bgm.mp3"));  
    gameMusic.play();
    gameMusic.setOnCompletionListener(Music.OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(Music aMusic){  
            actionResolver.getLeaderboardGPGS();  

        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: hmmm just think, when imComplete will be called?: `while(true){}imComplete();` ... it is a simple logic ... never

Answer (score 3):

Just add `new` before Music.OnCompletionListener() and it should work.

```
gameMusic.setOnCompletionListener(new Music.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(Music aMusic) {  
        actionResolver.getLeaderboardGPGS();  

    }
});
```

Since you're passing an object (that implements OnCompletionListener), it has to be created with `new` as always.

Comment: please explain why it worked for you, and why dint it work for the person asking the question